# Group by column in panda bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm running the groupby utility function on my dataframe object and I want to generate a bar chart after this. I'm expecting two bars next to each i.e one for each week:

Here is the code:

```
        df3 = (
            self.df
                .groupby(by=['week', 'type'], dropna=False)
                .sum()
                .unstack()
        )
```

which produces that:

```
type                              type1       type2
week                                     
1                             81.44            NaN
2                            591.30          1900.0
3                             91.10            NaN
4                            146.48          11000.0
5                            218.76            NaN
```

I'm kinda struggling now to plot it by calling:

```
axs.bar(numpy.arange(5, 1), df3)
```

which outputs "ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape".

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the [.bar() method](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html) also with the height of the single columns (i.e. your dataframe columns).

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 'type1', 81.44], 
        [2, 'type1', 591.3], 
        [2, 'type2', 1900], 
        [3, 'type1', 91.1], 
        [4, 'type1',146.48], 
        [4, 'type2', 11000], 
        [5, 'type1', 218.76]
], columns=['week', 'type', 'value'])

df3 = df.groupby(by=['week', 'type'])\
                .sum()\
                .unstack()

# Create plot

# Define the variables to display
bars = [df3.value.type1, df3.value.type2]

# Create the axes
axs = plt.subplot(111)            

# Plot 'type1'
axs.bar(x = np.arange(1, 1 + len(bars[0])) - .15, height = bars[0], width = .2, data = df3)
# Plot 'type2'
axs.bar(x = np.arange(1,1 + len(bars[1])) + .15, height = bars[1], width = .2, data = df3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This creates what you want:

```
df3.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: I specifically mentioned that I have to run it on Axes object not DF, seems like they handle things differently.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the option `ax` to `df3.plot`?

```
df3.plot.bar(ax=axs)
```